# Group by date range and check duplicate pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to see if I can find duplicate records happened in the year

I know how to find when it is just the year but the date range and find the duplicate and remove the duplicate seems a bit tough. I am beginner so pleas can anyone help ?

Comment: Why just for 2021?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = df[~df.loc[df['Date'].str.contains('2021')].duplicated(keep=False)
            .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)]
print(out)

# Output
         Date Transaction
0  31/12/2020   PURCHASES
1  31/12/2020       Sales
2  31/12/2020       Sales
```

Comment: How do I remove the duplicate transactions ?

Comment: Do you mean for 2020?

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicated transactions even the first one? If yes, just add `keep=False` as parameter of `duplicated` method to remove all duplicates

Comment: Thank you so much brother. It Yes I wanted to remove all the duplicate in the year 2021.

Comment: Is the full date does matter? If you have a transaction PURCHASES on 2021-03-10 and 2021-03-13 do you consider it's a duplicate or not?

Comment: Never mind I got it. There unique ID in the dataset. 
my fault. Sorry I bothered you

Comment: Not a problem, the important thing is that it works for you!

Comment: And I learned thanks to you